# Relative and absolute positioning issues with Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a GUI that requires both relative and absolute positioning. I need the absolute positioning (I believe), because the elements displayed change dynamically and I don't want the GUI to resize all the time.

Note: I am trying to create a grid of 4 lines of 5 checkboxes each.

Here is the code.

```
    final int MAXNUMBEROFLABELSPERROW = 5;
    final int defaultCheckBoxWidth = 60;
    final int defaultCheckBoxHeigth = 60;

    JLabel bigBlindRemoveLabel = new JLabel("Remove big blind numbers", SwingConstants.CENTER);

    JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonsPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel buttonsSubPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonsSubPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    removeButton = new JButton("Remove");
    removeButton.addActionListener(this);

    removeAllButton = new JButton("Remove All");
    removeAllButton.addActionListener(this);

    buttonsSubPanel.add(removeButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    buttonsSubPanel.add(removeAllButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    buttonsPanel.add(buttonsSubPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    buttonsPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(50, 20, 50, 20));

    JPanel checkboxesSubPanel = new JPanel();
    checkboxesSubPanel.setLayout(null);

    // Create 20 check boxes and fill the list field with big blind numbers
    for (int index = 0; index <= TOTALNUMBEROFCHECKBOXES - 1; index++)
    {
        numberCheckBoxes[index] = new JCheckBox();
        numberCheckBoxes[index].setSize(defaultCheckBoxWidth, defaultCheckBoxHeigth);
        numberCheckBoxes[index].setSelected(false);
        numberCheckBoxes[index].setLocation(
                defaultCheckBoxWidth * (index % MAXNUMBEROFLABELSPERROW) + 10,
                (index / MAXNUMBEROFLABELSPERROW) * defaultCheckBoxHeigth + defaultCheckBoxHeigth);
        numberCheckBoxes[index].setVisible(false);

        checkboxesSubPanel.add(numberCheckBoxes[index]);
    }

    checkboxesSubPanel.setSize(
            numberCheckBoxes[TOTALNUMBEROFCHECKBOXES - 1].getX()
                    + numberCheckBoxes[TOTALNUMBEROFCHECKBOXES - 1].getWidth() + 20,
            numberCheckBoxes[TOTALNUMBEROFCHECKBOXES - 1].getY()
                    + numberCheckBoxes[TOTALNUMBEROFCHECKBOXES - 1].getHeight() + 20);

    resultsPanel.add(bigBlindRemoveLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    resultsPanel.add(checkboxesSubPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    resultsPanel.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

    JFrame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(resultsPanel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
```

What I am looking for (done all with absolute positioning, which I am trying to improve)

[image]

What I am seeing instead with the code posted above

[image]

My problem is that the section is displayed, but its size changes dynamically if I change the checkboxes text (which I am trying to avoid). Also, I am not sure why, all the checkboxes are displayed on one line (I have used the same code with an absolute positioning before without issues). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. Don't use a null layout. Don't set the size. If you use the proper layout manager or combination of nested panels with layout managers you will not have a problem.

Comment: Didn't I just see this very same question about an hour or three ago??

Comment: The question's title is the same (the previous was actually inaccurate, so I fixed it), but the question itself is not :). Good eye!

Comment: The use of appropriate layout managers will allow dynamic content to resize/change automatically.  Remember, you can use multiple/compound layouts to achieve very complex layouts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need the absolute positioning (I believe), because the elements displayed change dynamically and I don't want the GUI to resize all the time.

I think you can't see the forest for the trees.  Remember, you're not stuck to using just a single layout manager, you can use compound containers/layouts to achieve some very complex layouts.

You could also use the features of the layout managers, `EmptyBorder`s and in the case of buttons, margins to adjust sizes of the controls and spacing.

[image: Layout]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.Scrollable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.MatteBorder;

public class TestLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLayout();
    }

    public TestLayout() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 0, 4, 0);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.weightx = 1;

            add(new JLabel("Big binds of first level: 25/50", JLabel.CENTER), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            SelectionPane selectionPane = new SelectionPane();
            selectionPane.setBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 0, 0, 0, Color.BLACK));
            add(selectionPane, gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            FilterPane filterPane = new FilterPane();
            filterPane.setBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 1, 0, 0, Color.BLACK));
            add(filterPane, gbc);

            selectionPane.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    filterPane.setOptions(selectionPane.getSelectedValues());
                }
            });
        }

    }

    protected class SelectionPane extends JPanel {

        private JList<Integer> listValues;
        private DefaultListModel<Integer> listModel;

        public SelectionPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            add(new JLabel("Add bind numbers to queries"), gbc);

            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            listModel = new DefaultListModel();
            for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
                listModel.addElement(index);
            }
            listValues = new JList(listModel);
            add(new JScrollPane(listValues), gbc);

            gbc.weighty = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            gbc.ipadx = 10;
            gbc.ipady = 10;
            JButton add = new JButton("Add");
            add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    fireActionPerformed();
                }
            });
            add(add, gbc);
        }

        public List<Integer> getSelectedValues() {

            return Collections.unmodifiableList(listValues.getSelectedValuesList());

        }

        public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
            listenerList.add(ActionListener.class, listener);
        }

        public void removeActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
            listenerList.remove(ActionListener.class, listener);
        }

        protected void fireActionPerformed() {
            ActionListener[] listeners = listenerList.getListeners(ActionListener.class);
            if (listeners.length > 0) {
                ActionEvent evt = new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "Selection.add");
                for (ActionListener listener : listeners) {
                    listener.actionPerformed(evt);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    protected class FilterPane extends JPanel {

        private OptionsPane optionsPane;

        public FilterPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            add(new JLabel("Remove big blind numbers"), gbc);

            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            gbc.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            optionsPane = new OptionsPane();
            add(new JScrollPane(optionsPane), gbc);

            gbc.weighty = 0;
            gbc.gridheight = 1;
            gbc.weightx = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.ipadx = 10;
            gbc.ipady = 10;
            JButton remove = new JButton("Remove");
            add(remove, gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            JButton removeAll = new JButton("Remove All");
            add(removeAll, gbc);
        }

        public void setOptions(List<Integer> options) {
            optionsPane.setOptions(options);
        }

        protected class OptionsPane extends JPanel implements Scrollable {

            public OptionsPane() {
                setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            }

            public void setOptions(List<Integer> options) {
                removeAll();
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.gridy = 0;
                gbc.weightx = 1;
                gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
                for (Integer option : options) {
                    JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox(option.toString());
                    add(cb, gbc);
                    gbc.gridx++;
                    if (gbc.gridx % 5 == 0) {
                        gbc.gridx = 0;
                        gbc.gridy++;
                    }
                }

                gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.gridy++;
                gbc.weighty = 1;
                add(new JLabel(), gbc);

                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
                return new Dimension(210, 100);
            }

            @Override
            public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
                return 64;
            }

            @Override
            public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
                return 64;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
                return getPreferredSize().width
                        <= getParent().getSize().width;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
                return getPreferredSize().height
                        <= getParent().getSize().height;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Wow, very detailed answer, very much appreciated! Thank you for spending the time! (Btw, your UI looks so much better :))

Comment: @BenoitGoderre If you get the chance to run the, try resizing the window and see what happens ;)

Comment: Very nice indeed :). Now, I need to understand that code!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the useful feedback, was able to find my answer by using a grid layout and setting the checkboxes minimum size with numberCheckBoxes[index].setMinimumSize(new Dimension(2, 0));

Thank you again for the help!

Comment: If you're using absolute layouts, using `setMiniumSize/preferredSize/maximumSize` is irrelevant, as they are tips used by the layout manager API to make decisions about how to best layout values. It's also generally discouraged to use these setters as they tend to cause way more issues then they solve